# Linux Enable/Disable Protocols Programmatically

Tags: c, linux, ipv4

I want to enable/disable IPv4/IPv6 in Linux programmatically using C. Is this possible? If yes, kindly please let me know how to do this and any reference to sample program would also be very helpful.

Comment: Are you sure to want to disable IP on `localhost` ?

Answer (score 2):

See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66574/how-can-i-disable-ipv6-in-custom-built-embedded-setup

Unfortunately, the `_sysctl(2)` system call API is deprecated, so you are left with writing to files in `/proc/` directly (which is easy enough from C, just a little funny smelling):

The important bits seem to be writing a textual value of `1` (text, not int) to at least the first of these two files, and possibly both:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/disable_ipv6
```

As for IPv4, it's less clear to me.  Do you really need to disable IPv4 while leaving IPv6 running?